# How to convert seconds to day/hour/minute/seconds

Tags: bash, dmesg

I'm trying to translate this time format `21410.912099` into this `12d 1h 14m 17.912 s`

I tried using such a script, but it doesn't work (can't parse a point) :(

```
converts() {
t=$1
d=$((t/60/60/24))
h=$((t/60/60%24))
m=$((t/60%60))
s=$((t%60))

if [ $d -gt 0 ]; then
        [ $d = 1 ] && printf "%d day " $d || printf "%d days " $d
fi
if [ $h -gt 0 ]; then
        [ $h = 1 ] && printf "%d hour " $h || printf "%d hours " $h
fi
if [ $m -gt 0 ]; then
        [ $m = 1 ] && printf "%d minute " $m || printf "%d minutes " $m
fi
if [ $d = 0 ] && [ $h = 0 ] && [ $m = 0 ]; then
        [ $s = 1 ] && printf "%d second" $s || printf "%d seconds" $s
fi
printf '\n' 
}
```

Comment: `bash` or `sh`? Do you have GNU versions of utilities such as `date`?

Comment: 1. Bash
2. seconds.milliseconds

Comment: 21410 seconds isn't going to get you 12d 1h 14m 17s no matter how hard you try (there are 86400 seconds in a typical day). Also, if you've 912099 milliseconds then that's 912 seconds. Perhaps you meant microseconds or nanoseconds?

Comment: Yes, apparently, I did not understand the `dmesg` format from the description in man :(

Comment: ufff, @КотикВася: Why didn't you just ask for how to show `dmesg` times in Human-readable form? That's a fair bit easier, because `dmesg` already brings the things you need!

Comment: for example, `dmesg --time-format iso` gives you unambigously parseable times in ISO datetime format; `dmesg --ctime` gives you the time in your console's set language (locale) settings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524443/understanding-the-kernel-dmesg-timestamp

Dealt with the format :)

Marcus, hi :)

Now I need just such a recording format (iso is not suitable according to the requirements from the teacher)

Comment: Do you want to see zero units (like 0d 0h 3m 4.200s) or suppressw them ?

Answer (score 2):

Split the value into an array using the `.` as delimiter.

Use the Bash built-in `printf` to reformat the seconds as an interval since the epoch.

```
$ Input=1721410.912099
$ IFS='.' s_ms=( ${Input} )
$ declare -p s_ms
declare -a s_ms=([0]="1721410" [1]="912099")
$ printf -v Out '%(%-dd %-Hh %-Mm %-S)T.%s s' "${s_ms[0]}" "${s_ms[1]:0:3}"
$ declare -p Out
declare -- Out="20d 23h 10m 10.912 s"
```

Edit: sorry, this is buggy in at least three ways. I tested it with `3707.001234`.

(1) It has a one-off error in the days, because the base is 1970-01-**01**.

(2) It has a one-off error in the hours, which I cannot immediately see (I am on GMT but timezone is the obvious suspect). `date -d @0` reports `Thu  1 Jan 01:00:00 BST 1970` also. British Summer Time in January ???

(3) Intervals above `2678400` are going to discard whole months.

Tricky things, these dates. My apologies. But how to deal with fractions of a second is correct -- parse it and substring it.

Additional from Google: BST and the British Experiment

All-year British Summer Time (BST) was in force from February 1968 until October 1971.

Comment: in (2), the offset comes from the timezone and so also depends on your location. E.g. for `printf '%(%-dd %-Hh %-Mm %-S %Z %z)T\n' 0`, I get `1d 2h 0m 0 EET +0200`. I guess you could use `TZ=UTC printf ...` to counter that. But the issue in (1) is still there and since no month has day 0, that's going to be hard to work around without splitting the number of days out to subtract it manually, but then you could just do the divisions and modulos by hand to get all the fields...

Comment: @ilkkachu  I was 90% through an arithmetic solution, but you beat me to it. I like your detail with day/days etc. I split the `.` using `IFS read -r` from a here_string, but `%(...)T` is really only good for actual dates. I should probably remove my answer in a day or two. EET -- I always wondered where you were.

Comment: that wasn't mine, it was in the question already. I just added the splitting on the dot...

Comment: @ilkkachu  So it was. I was fooled by the first sentence wanting `into this 12d 1h 14m 17.912 s`, and failed to read the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the fractional part of the time, you can use the   `${var##prefix}` and `${var%%suffix}` expansions to split the value. They remove the longest matching prefix and suffix from the value of `$var`.

So with the two lines with comments added:

```
converts() {
    t=$1
    case $t in
        *.*) tfrac=${t##*.}       # fractional seconds
             t=${t%%.*}           # full seconds
             ;;
          *) tfrac=0              # no decimal point
             ;;
    esac

    d=$((t/60/60/24))
    h=$((t/60/60%24))
    m=$((t/60%60))
    s=$((t%60))
    
    if [ $d -gt 0 ]; then
            [ $d = 1 ] && printf "%d day " $d || printf "%d days " $d
    fi
    if [ $h -gt 0 ]; then
            [ $h = 1 ] && printf "%d hour " $h || printf "%d hours " $h
    fi
    if [ $m -gt 0 ]; then
            [ $m = 1 ] && printf "%d minute " $m || printf "%d minutes " $m
    fi
    if [ $d = 0 ] && [ $h = 0 ] && [ $m = 0 ]; then
            [ $s = 1 ] && printf "%d second" $s || printf "%d seconds" $s
    fi
    printf '\n' 
}
```

we get e.g.

```
$ converts $(( 1*86400 + 23*3600 + 45*60 + 6))
1 day 23 hours 45 minutes
```

We need to check if the input has the decimal point before trying to remove parts of it, since if there is no dot, `${t##*.}` just returns `$t`.

I'll leave it to you to decide where you want to use `tfrac`. Maybe something like

```
printf "%d.%s seconds" $s $tfrac
```

(don't use `%d.%d`, it'll remove leading zeroes and e.g. `123.05` would turn into `123.5`)

---

Or, in the `12d 1h 14m 17.912s` format:

```
converts() {
    t=$1
    case $t in
        *.*) tfrac=${t##*.}       # fractional seconds
             t=${t%%.*}           # full seconds
             ;;
          *) tfrac=0              # no decimal point
             ;;
    esac
    d=$((t/60/60/24))
    h=$((t/60/60%24))
    m=$((t/60%60))
    s=$((t%60))

    printf "%dd %dh %dm %d.%ss\n" "$d" "$h" "$m" "$s" "$tfrac"
}
```

and

```
$ converts  $(( 1*86400 + 23*3600 + 45*60 + 6)).987
1d 23h 45m 6.987s
```